# Apps has stopped,while click the item in an listview in the second time

Tags: java, android

Error showing in logcat
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165193, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.recipestutors.ItemListBaseAdapter)]
ItemListBaseAdapter.java

```
 public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<Recipedetails> itemDetailsrrayList;

    private Integer[] imgid = {
            R.drawable.vegeterian,
            R.drawable.nonveg,
            R.drawable.pickels,
            R.drawable.soup,
            R.drawable.sweets,
            R.drawable.cakes,
            R.drawable.icecreams,
            R.drawable.chinesevegdishes,
            R.drawable.chinesenonveg,
            R.drawable.chinesenoodles,
            R.drawable.chinesesoup,
            R.drawable.godhumaivegadai,
            R.drawable.soyamorekoozh,
            R.drawable.tomatokulambu,
            R.drawable.tomatoupma,
            R.drawable.vadanavratrispecial,
            R.drawable.eggkurma,
            R.drawable.milagu,
            R.drawable.rasam,
            R.drawable.vegetablekootu,
            R.drawable.avial,
            R.drawable.kothavarangaicurry,
            R.drawable.allepeyfishcurry,
            R.drawable.spicymadraschicken,
            R.drawable.prawns,
            R.drawable.keralachickenstew,
            R.drawable.nilgirichickenkorma,
            R.drawable.pepperchickencurry,
            R.drawable.chettiandchicken,
            R.drawable.prawnmasala,
            R.drawable.beeffry,
            R.drawable.crispyfish,
            R.drawable.amlapickle,
            R.drawable.avakaipickle,
            R.drawable.capsicumpickle,
            R.drawable.lemonpickle,
            R.drawable.onionpickle,
            R.drawable.mangopickle,
            R.drawable.tendermangopickle,
            R.drawable.tomatopickle,
            R.drawable.chillipickles,
            R.drawable.gingerpickle,
            R.drawable.garlicsoup,
            R.drawable.mixedvegsoup,
            R.drawable.chickenmanchowsoup,
            R.drawable.cleartomatosoup,
            R.drawable.sweetcornvegetablesoup,
            R.drawable.prawnandnoodlesoup,
            R.drawable.beetrootsoup,
            R.drawable.capsicumsoup,
            R.drawable.muttonsoup,
            R.drawable.spinachsoup,
            R.drawable.vegcurry,
            R.drawable.mushroommutter,
            R.drawable.alooparatha,
            R.drawable.daltadka,
            R.drawable.aloomethi,
            R.drawable.rajma,
            R.drawable.paneerbhujri,
            R.drawable.alooghobi,
            R.drawable.aloosabzi,
            R.drawable.kadhaipaneer,
            R.drawable.chickenwithbellpeppers,
            R.drawable.butterchicken,
            R.drawable.fishkorma,
            R.drawable.prawnfry,
            R.drawable.tandoorichicken,
            R.drawable.maccherjholfish,
            R.drawable.shamikabab,
            R.drawable.saagmeat,
            R.drawable.sindhichickenbiryani,
            R.drawable.punjabichickencurry,
            R.drawable.gulabjamun,
            R.drawable.basundi,
            R.drawable.peda,
            R.drawable.badhamhalwa,
            R.drawable.coconutburfi,
            R.drawable.kulfi,
            R.drawable.ladoo,
            R.drawable.mysorepak,
            R.drawable.ricekheer,
            R.drawable.badam,
            R.drawable.cauliflowersoup,
            R.drawable.cucumbersoup,
            R.drawable.tomatosoup,
            R.drawable.mulligatawnysoup,
            R.drawable.greenpeassoup,
            R.drawable.northindianmuttonsoup,
            R.drawable.chickennoodlesoup,
            R.drawable.spicybeansoup,
            R.drawable.eggdropsoup,
            R.drawable.springvegsoup,
            R.drawable.mushroomandseitan,
            R.drawable.tofuwith3spices,
            R.drawable.creamyvegpie,
            R.drawable.grilledvegmedley,
            R.drawable.bakedsquash,
            R.drawable.africanchickenstew,
            R.drawable.westafricanchicken,
            R.drawable.africanyamsoup,
            R.drawable.chickenchilliroast,
            R.drawable.chilliblackbeans,
            R.drawable.williecake,
            R.drawable.pumpkingingercupcakes,
            R.drawable.doublelayerpumpkincheesecake,
            R.drawable.carrotcake,
            R.drawable.sexcake,
            R.drawable.chocolatechipicecream,
            R.drawable.cookieicecream,
            R.drawable.cinnamonicecream,
            R.drawable.appleicecream,
            R.drawable.walnut,
            R.drawable.chineseaubergins,
            R.drawable.spicycucumber,
            R.drawable.chinesemushrooms,
            R.drawable.chinesegobi,
            R.drawable.spicytofu,
            R.drawable.chinesetilchicken,
            R.drawable.chickenmoongali,
            R.drawable.sweetsourchicken,
            R.drawable.cherrychicken,
            R.drawable.mymasalachicken,
            R.drawable.coldseasamenoodles,
            R.drawable.sobanoodles,
            R.drawable.noodleswithtofu,
            R.drawable.chinesevegandbeef,
            R.drawable.noodleswithpepper,
            R.drawable.jhingasoup,
            R.drawable.masalachickensoup,
            R.drawable.cabbagesoup,
            R.drawable.chinesepumpkinsoup,
            R.drawable.baconsoup,





            };



    private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

    public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recipedetails> results) {
        itemDetailsrrayList = results;
        l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
            //holder.recipeLinkWiki = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recipeLinkWiki);
            holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemDescription());
        //holder.recipeLinkWiki.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getUrlWiki());
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(imgid[itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() - 1]);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
         //TextView recipeLinkWiki;
        TextView txt_itemName;
        TextView txt_itemDescription;
        //TextView txt_recipeLinkWiki;
        ImageView itemImage;
    }
}
```

Logcat Error:

```
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165193, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.recipestutors.ItemListBaseAdapter)]
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3403)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 03-18 12:59:18.592: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 03-18 12:59:21.032: I/Process(2010): Sending signal. PID: 2010 SIG: 9
 03-18 12:59:21.672: E/Trace(2031): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: post your logcat message

Comment: i posted my log cat ,can you look at that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is that your are updating your `Adapter` ouside of UI Thread and it caused your Exception.

I guess that you need to make sure that you are manipulating with UI elements only from UI Thread. And if you are using AsyncTask so you need to call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()` method

Comment: ,can you tell how to do that one,where i want to put that code

Answer (score 0):

*The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.*

This issue means that the data that your basicAdapter is trying to adapt for the listView was changed, obviously means your `itemDetailsrrayList` doesn't contain the same data.

I suppose that you are manipulating this list in your activities.

That's normal to happen, and what you should do, is to notify the adapter by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in onResume callback of the activity using the adapter.

Comment: @kkarthickk, **WHAT** : as you can see, what's in common between the two responses is that you must call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. **WHERE** : depends on your scenario. **WHEN** : whenever you change the list passed to the adapter, and this last wasn't notified or recreated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code i got
ItemListAdapter.java

```
 public synchronized   void refreshAdapter(ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
    //itemDetailsrrayList.clear();
    itemDetailsrrayList = items;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and in mylistviewactivity.java

```
private void refreshYourAdapter(final ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
```

//this is what I meant. The error clearly states you are not updating the adapter on the UI thread
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
_itemListAdapter.refreshAdapter(items);
}
});
}
and

```
@Override
```

protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
_itemListAdapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details);
refreshYourAdapter(GetSearchResults());
lv1.setAdapter(_itemListAdapter);

} we have to add these things in your listview activity it will works very fine and remove static in idemlistadapter