# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.content adapter is not modified from a background thread

Tags: java, android

this error showing in my logcat

```
03-19 12:48:54.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2066): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165193, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.recipestutors.ItemListBaseAdapter)]
```

Itemlistadapter.java

```
ublic class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static ArrayList<Recipedetails> itemDetailsrrayList;

private Integer[] imgid = {
                R.drawable.vegeterian,
                R.drawable.nonveg,
                R.drawable.pickels,
                R.drawable.soup,
                R.drawable.sweets,
                R.drawable.cakes,
                R.drawable.icecreams,
                R.drawable.chinesevegdishes,
                R.drawable.chinesenonveg,
                R.drawable.chinesenoodles,
                R.drawable.chinesesoup,
                R.drawable.godhumaivegadai,
                R.drawable.soyamorekoozh,
                R.drawable.tomatokulambu,
                R.drawable.tomatoupma,
                R.drawable.vadanavratrispecial,
                R.drawable.eggkurma,
                R.drawable.milagu,
                R.drawable.rasam,
                R.drawable.vegetablekootu,
                R.drawable.avial,
                R.drawable.kothavarangaicurry,
                R.drawable.allepeyfishcurry,
                R.drawable.spicymadraschicken,
                R.drawable.prawns,
                R.drawable.keralachickenstew,
                R.drawable.nilgirichickenkorma,
                R.drawable.pepperchickencurry,
                R.drawable.chettiandchicken,
                R.drawable.prawnmasala,
                R.drawable.beeffry,
                R.drawable.crispyfish,
                R.drawable.amlapickle,
                R.drawable.avakaipickle,
                R.drawable.capsicumpickle,
                R.drawable.lemonpickle,
                R.drawable.onionpickle,
                R.drawable.mangopickle,
                R.drawable.tendermangopickle,
                R.drawable.tomatopickle,
                R.drawable.chillipickles,
                R.drawable.gingerpickle,
                R.drawable.garlicsoup,
                R.drawable.mixedvegsoup,
                R.drawable.chickenmanchowsoup,
                R.drawable.cleartomatosoup,
                R.drawable.sweetcornvegetablesoup,
                R.drawable.prawnandnoodlesoup,
                R.drawable.beetrootsoup,
                R.drawable.capsicumsoup,
                R.drawable.muttonsoup,
                R.drawable.spinachsoup,
                R.drawable.vegcurry,
                R.drawable.mushroommutter,
                R.drawable.alooparatha,
                R.drawable.daltadka,
                R.drawable.aloomethi,
                R.drawable.rajma,
                R.drawable.paneerbhujri,
                R.drawable.alooghobi,
                R.drawable.aloosabzi,
                R.drawable.kadhaipaneer,
                R.drawable.chickenwithbellpeppers,
                R.drawable.butterchicken,
                R.drawable.fishkorma,
                R.drawable.prawnfry,
                R.drawable.tandoorichicken,
                R.drawable.maccherjholfish,
                R.drawable.shamikabab,
                R.drawable.saagmeat,
                R.drawable.sindhichickenbiryani,
                R.drawable.punjabichickencurry,
                R.drawable.gulabjamun,
                R.drawable.basundi,
                R.drawable.peda,
                R.drawable.badhamhalwa,
                R.drawable.coconutburfi,
                R.drawable.kulfi,
                R.drawable.ladoo,
                R.drawable.mysorepak,
                R.drawable.ricekheer,
                R.drawable.badam,
                R.drawable.cauliflowersoup,
                R.drawable.cucumbersoup,
                R.drawable.tomatosoup,
                R.drawable.mulligatawnysoup,
                R.drawable.greenpeassoup,
                R.drawable.northindianmuttonsoup,
                R.drawable.chickennoodlesoup,
                R.drawable.spicybeansoup,
                R.drawable.eggdropsoup,
                R.drawable.springvegsoup,
                R.drawable.mushroomandseitan,
                R.drawable.tofuwith3spices,
                R.drawable.creamyvegpie,
                R.drawable.grilledvegmedley,
                R.drawable.bakedsquash,
                R.drawable.africanchickenstew,
                R.drawable.westafricanchicken,
                R.drawable.africanyamsoup,
                R.drawable.chickenchilliroast,
                R.drawable.chilliblackbeans,
                R.drawable.williecake,
                R.drawable.pumpkingingercupcakes,
                R.drawable.doublelayerpumpkincheesecake,
                R.drawable.carrotcake,
                R.drawable.sexcake,
                R.drawable.chocolatechipicecream,
                R.drawable.cookieicecream,
                R.drawable.cinnamonicecream,
                R.drawable.appleicecream,
                R.drawable.walnut,
                R.drawable.chineseaubergins,
                R.drawable.spicycucumber,
                R.drawable.chinesemushrooms,
                R.drawable.chinesegobi,
                R.drawable.spicytofu,
                R.drawable.chinesetilchicken,
                R.drawable.chickenmoongali,
                R.drawable.sweetsourchicken,
                R.drawable.cherrychicken,
                R.drawable.mymasalachicken,
                R.drawable.coldseasamenoodles,
                R.drawable.sobanoodles,
                R.drawable.noodleswithtofu,
                R.drawable.chinesevegandbeef,
                R.drawable.noodleswithpepper,
                R.drawable.jhingasoup,
                R.drawable.masalachickensoup,
                R.drawable.cabbagesoup,
                R.drawable.chinesepumpkinsoup,
                R.drawable.baconsoup,


                };



private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recipedetails> results) {
        itemDetailsrrayList = results;
        l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
                holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemDescription());
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(imgid[itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() - 1]);
        return convertView;
}
public synchronized   void refreshAdapter(ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
    itemDetailsrrayList.clear();
    itemDetailsrrayList.addAll(items);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}

static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_itemName;
        TextView txt_itemDescription;
        ImageView itemImage;
}
}
```

soutindian.java

```
public class SouthIndian extends Activity {
ItemListBaseAdapter _itemListAdapter;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<Recipedetails> image_details = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

        _itemListAdapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details);

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(_itemListAdapter);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                        Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        Recipedetails obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails)o;
                        Toast.makeText(SouthIndian.this, "You have chosen : " + " " +      obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        switch(obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber())
                        {
                            case 1:
                                 Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,
                                                 AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class);    
                     startActivity(newActivity);
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                Intent new1Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,
                                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity1.class);    
                            startActivity(new1Activity);
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                Intent new2Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,
                                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity2.class);    
                            startActivity(new2Activity);
                                break;

                            case 4:
                                Intent new3Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,
                                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity3.class);    
                            startActivity(new3Activity);
                                break;        

                           default:
                                   Toast.makeText(SouthIndian.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                }
        });

        refreshYourAdapter(GetSearchResults());
    }

    // THIS IS WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE MORE OR LESS. THIS IS AS MUCH AS I CAN HELP

    private void refreshYourAdapter(final ArrayList<Recipedetails> newData) {
         //this is what I meant. The error clearly states you are not updating the adapter on the UI thread
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 _itemListAdapter.refreshAdapter(newData);
             }
         });
    }

    private ArrayList<Recipedetails> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<Recipedetails> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

        Recipedetails item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Recipes made by raw materials");
            item_details.setImageNumber(1);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Non-Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Flesh of sweet animals");
        item_details.setImageNumber(2);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Pickels");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Touchable dish  by Homemade");
        item_details.setImageNumber(3);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Soups");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Startup for our food");
            item_details.setImageNumber(4);
        results.add(item_details);

        return results;
    }
}
```

Northindian.java

```
public class NorthIndian  extends Activity {
 ItemListBaseAdapter _itemListAdapter;


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<Recipedetails> image_details = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

        _itemListAdapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details);

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(_itemListAdapter);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Recipedetails obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails)o;
                Toast.makeText(NorthIndian.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                switch(obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber())
                {
                    case 1:
                         Intent newActivity = new Intent(NorthIndian.this, 
                                 AndroidTabLayoutActivity4.class);     
                         startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Intent new1Activity = new Intent(NorthIndian.this, 
                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity5.class);     
                        startActivity(new1Activity);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        Intent new2Activity = new Intent(NorthIndian.this, 
                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity6.class);     
                        startActivity(new2Activity);
                        break; 

                    case 4:
                        Intent new3Activity = new Intent(NorthIndian.this, 
                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity7.class);     
                        startActivity(new3Activity);
                        break;      

                   default:
                       Toast.makeText(NorthIndian.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }  
        });
        refreshYourAdapter(GetSearchResults());
    }
  private void refreshYourAdapter(final ArrayList<Recipedetails> newData) {
      //this is what I meant. The error clearly states you are not updating the adapter on the UI thread
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              _itemListAdapter.refreshAdapter(newData);
          }
      });
 }

    private ArrayList<Recipedetails> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<Recipedetails> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

        Recipedetails item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Recipes made by raw materials");
        item_details.setImageNumber(1);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Non-Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Flesh of sweet animals");
        item_details.setImageNumber(2);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Sweets");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Tasty sweets made from indians");
        item_details.setImageNumber(5);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Soups");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Startup for our food");
        item_details.setImageNumber(4);
        results.add(item_details);




        return results;
    }
}
```

after clicking the first time in listview,it will goes to the function,if we come back again clicking the next item in the listview,it shows my application has stopped.
**My problem not solved i tried all the ways**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); where i have to use these line for my error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491876/how-to-use-adapter-notifydatasetchanged-where-i-have-to-use-these-line-for-my)

Comment: i tried those ways also,its not working

Comment: Have you tried adding whole values in adapter from class where you have used it rather than where you have declared it?

Comment: @Harpreet you can see in this link what i did http://pastebin.com/DXdvB5HC

Comment: There is no code like `ArrayAdapter<Type> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Type>(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, listItems);`

Comment: How will it set those items to your listview?

Comment: @Harpreet where and how i added those code,can you edit and tell my code,,by the itemlist adapter

Comment: what can i do and how to solve these problems

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26519/discussion-between-harpreet-and-kkarthickk)

Comment: I gave my answer to this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477699/apps-has-stopped-while-click-the-item-in-an-listview-in-the-second-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two code is needed 
in our listadapter

```
public synchronized   void refreshAdapter(ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
        //itemDetailsrrayList.clear();
        itemDetailsrrayList = items;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and our listview activity also

```
private void refreshYourAdapter(final ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
//this is what I meant. The error clearly states you are not updating the adapter on the UI thread
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
_itemListAdapter.refreshAdapter(items);
}
});
}
```

and one more code also in listview

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>(); 
    _itemListAdapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details);
    refreshYourAdapter(GetSearchResults());
    lv1.setAdapter(_itemListAdapter);

    }
```